# How to redirect http url to https url?

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, ssl, https

I want to redirect my wordpress login page to use HTTPS but do not want the rest of the site using it. I know how to redirect all the site via HTTP to HTTPS but not just a specific URL.

So I want http://example.com/wp-admin to go to https://example.com/wp-admin

This is what I currently have below and I have tried adding bits in but not got there.

```
Redirect / https://example.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mod_rewrite to enable https for a specific url.

Try the following in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```